# Pagination on category home page

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

i have a blog where posts are shown in under different category id. In category home page i want to show 10 posts per page. But my pagination is not working. Can anybody help please?

//////////Controller///////

```
public function categoryDetails($category_id)
    {

    $data = array();
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'Welcome/categoryDetails/'.$category_id;
    $data['total_rows'] = $this->WelcomeModel->select_number_of_published_blog_by_category_id($category_id);
    $config['per_page'] = 2;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $data['allPost'] = $this->SuperEditorModel->select_all_blog_post_with_category($category_id,$config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));
    $this->load->view('frontend/master', $data);
```

Comment: Need to see your code

Comment: you may need to create some routes also in routes.php http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html#examples

Comment: This also may help http://www.sitepoint.com/pagination-with-codeigniter/

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `create_links()` function to load the pagination links. You can add it to your `data` array and pass it to the view

```
$data["pagination_links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
$this->load->view('frontend/master', $data);
```

From the documentation:

> create_links()
>
> Returns:  HTML-formatted pagination
>
> Return type:  string
>
> Returns a “pagination” bar, containing the generated links or an empty
>   string if there’s just a single page.

Answer (score 0):

add this in your controller to create pagination link

```
$data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
```

And your view page where are you want to view pagination link

```
<?php echo $link; ?>
```